# How to get notification on wrong windows login

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

Is there a possibility using the Windows API to implement a service in C++ in which to intercept when a user tries to login to windows, but inserts a wrong password?
I have searched on msdn but couldn't find something useful. The functionality should work on Windows 7, 8 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service may watch the Security Event Log for failed logon attempts. API description is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx

For this to work, security auditing must be enabled via Group Policy or Domain Policy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not instant, but you can [audit logon failures](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671957(v=ws.10).aspx) and [keep an eye](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385771(v=vs.85).aspx) on the event log.